# How to use jQuery UI from Blazor component

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, blazor

I am working through some Blazor examples, and while trying to work with some JSInterop solutions, I ran into an issue with jQuery UI elements. I am not a proficient Javascript programmer, but I am proficient enough with .NET so I may be missing something simple. The first jQuery UI component I have tried to work with is the "resizable" component, found here: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Here is what my current code looks like:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am certain that the issue isn't with loading the libraries, and I have placed the script after loading `blazor.server.js`.

Now, my **Index.cshtml** has the following in the html portion:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
            <div class="row row-no-gutters" style="width: 100%; height: 50%">
                <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Ideally, this would yield a resizable div, but the resulting html element is not resizable. From my understanding, Blazor JSInterop no longer requires JS functions to be registered. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that of timing: your jQuery function executes before your Blazor app has rendered.

The way I solved this is by replacing the "onready" (`$(...)`) function with a named function (e.g. `onBlazorReady`) that I then invoke from my Blazor's `MainLayout` component at the right time.

The right time being `OnAfterRender`.

For example:

MainLayout.razor:

```
@code {
   [Inject]
   protected IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }

   protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
   {
       if (firstRender)
           JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("onBlazorReady");
   }
}
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script>
        onBlazorReady() {
            $("#resizable").resizable();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I'm injecting `IJSInterop` so that I can call my `onBlazorReady` JS function after the LayoutComponent has rendered.

Comment: this example does not work? https://blazorfiddle.com/s/kg13ms5x

Comment: I provided the code to show where to put what - not as a fully functioning example - you would need a full project for things to work out.

Comment: @Isaac care to explain?

Comment: I have tried all of these and none of them seem to work with my code. I have a Blazor WASM PWA.

In my function I added the line:

prompt('hey');

It appeared before while the page was still showing 'Loading...'.  So, I know my C# code is calling the proper function, but my animations are not showing up.  I am guessing that it is still a timing issue, but I can't find any other lifecycle event to use.  Could it be something with the WASM and/or PWA that would be interfering with the animations?

Brad

Answer (score 11):

Works fine for me like this, to add datepicker from jquery ui:

Razor component file.

```
@code {
    protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("addDatePicker");
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }
}
```

Global razor file:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Magiro.Blazor</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
    </app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.addDatePicker = () => {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no need any more to add a method in the global index page (`_Hosts.cshtml` in ASP.NET Core 5.0), which would fill those file with view-specific logic and dependencies. At least with v5 we have `IJSObjectReference` allowing us to call `$('table').DataTable()` directly from our `.razor` file like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <!-- your data -->
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    [Inject]
    protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
        if (firstRender) {
            var jQuery = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("$", "table");
            await jQuery.InvokeVoidAsync("DataTable");
        }
    }
}
```

It's also possible to pass options to the plugin with an anonymous type. For example, to disable the search, we'd call in JS

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "searching": false
});
```

In Blazor we create an anonymous type with the same structure and pass it as parameter to the `DataTable` call:

```
var options = new {
    searching = false
};
await jQuery.InvokeVoidAsync("DataTable", options);
```

Answer (score 2):

The most probable cause is timing. The jQuery function gets executed before the DOM elements exists.

You should register the JS code as an interop function and call that after in `OnAfterRender` event.

Comment: Even though I’m not calling the jQuery function from a C# method? Basically just a new override method called `OnAfterRender()` that returns `JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync(“resizable”)` etc?

Comment: Yes, that will make sure the function is run when the DOM elements exist. In your example I'm pretty sure the timing is the problem.

Comment: Ok I will try that in the morning. I hadn’t thought of that - thanks for the advice!

Comment: I would suggest you sleep on it... Take into account that the resizable method should be defined in a namespace in the form: window.somenamespace.somemethod... good luck...

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need any JQuery function like `ready`, you can simply put those all required code into your custom js function which should run on ON_LOAD of your component as said by @Sipke Schoorstra in above answer