# JQuery data table not working in my Blazor and .NET core project

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to use JQuery datatable in my blazor project. I am using the CDN files to load the framework. This is my **_Host.cshtml** file:

```
@page "/"
@namespace Blazor.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Blazor</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute"
              crossorigin="anonymous"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" />
    </environment>
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>
            ())
        </App>
        <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#carTable').DataTable();
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in my **CarData.razor** file I connect the ID like this:

```
<table id="carTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
```

When I run the application it doesn't load the framework. I get **no** error in my console.

I have read about Javascript interop in this documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Somehow it doesn't read my CDN files from the JQuery datatable.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured it out:

In my **_Host.cshtml** I have this code:

```
<script>
 function DataTable() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#carTable').DataTable();
  });
 }
 </script>
```

Then in my **CarData.razor** I call this method like this:

```
 protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
 {

        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("DataTable");
 }
```

Don't forget to inject the library in your page:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be some DataTable elements left over when you leave your page. You need to remove all elements with IDispose.

For a complete tutorial, have a look at this post:

[How to add Data Tables to Blazor](https://gmtech.co.za/how-to-add-js-data-tables-to-your-blazor-project/)

Answer (score 1):

Sine ASP.NET Core 5.0 you can [directly access jQuery plugins like DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66308737/3276634) without having to define a wrapper-function globally:

```
@code {
    [Inject]
    protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
        if (firstRender) {
            var jQuery = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("$", "table");
            await jQuery.InvokeVoidAsync("DataTable");
        }
    }
}
```