# How to use Blazor to Invoke JQuery Function

Tags: blazor

new to blazor.  I need to use Bootstrap DateTime Picker. Has anyone used it before? I am stuck as to how to call the JQuery func. Understand there is JSRuntime.Invoke() but this one for normal java script function. Below is the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I place the Jquery in the Index.html script section:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
```

for normal JS integration, this will be used:
 await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync("");

But for the above, how to use this JsRuntime?

Please help.

Update:
This is an awesome control. I have some questions on the download.
 1) There are @code and @function with some func that are also in @code, which is which?
 2) It is possible to make the input control not able to edit ( so no need to validate if it is valid time or date when submit).

Comment: @code is the new @function - use @code now.  questions related to `NodatimePicker` would best be done via GitHub.  I'm not the author.

Comment: you nner override OnAfterRender, and call a function that call the jQuery function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274629/how-to-use-jquery-ui-from-blazor-component. But you can try with components from another blazor library and not use jQuery for this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying this rather than calling out to invoke JS

https://github.com/nheath99/NodaTimePicker

Comment: Thank. Just a quick one. Im not sure how this work. hope u can explain.I  will question the rest in that forum.                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo FormatProvider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    static LocalDate Today = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant().InUtc().LocalDateTime.Date;

    LocalDate? selectedDate2;   <<---What this means?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
```