# How to run JQuery codes in Blazor Server App

Tags: jquery, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a layout using HTML, CSS and jQuery. I tried to transfer my layout to Blazor Server App. I have the following codes:

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
    <link href='./css/font_awesome/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js:**

```
$('#sidebar-toggle-btn').click(function () {
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    if ($('.sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.sidenav-bottom').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        $('.sidenav-bottom').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('.sidenav-bottom i').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
});

$('.nav-list li a').click(function () {
    $('.nav-list li a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebar').mouseenter(function () {
        if (!$('.sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        }
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

The problem is that codes in `main.js` cannot be executed.
I studied [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274629/how-to-use-jquery-ui-from-blazor-component) but I could not solve my problem.
How can I solve that?

Comment: Your code only manipulates classes applied to elements. Blazor can do this without any of that. Take a closer look at what the template is already doing in particular NavMenu.razor

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using these modifications:

**MainLayout.razor:**

```
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("renderjQueryComponents");
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
}
```

**main.js:**

```
function renderjQueryComponents() {
    $('#sidebar-toggle-btn').click(function () {
        $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        if ($('.sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.sidenav-bottom').css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else {
            $('.sidenav-bottom').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('.sidenav-bottom i').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    });

    $('.nav-list li a').click(function () {
        $('.nav-list li a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sidebar').mouseenter(function () {
            if (!$('.sidebar').hasClass('active')) {
                $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
            }
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
}
```